# Big Query - how to write to existing cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have two columns: Column A contains cells of text and column B is a location reference.

I want to use Big Query to scan column A for a location reference (country) and then write that country to the adjacent cell in column B.

I already know how to search for rows containing a keyword, but I'm not sure how to get Big Query to write to already existing cells in my Google sheet (if this is even possible!) - essentially filling in the gaps in my table.

I would need to preserve the entire table too, so don't want to isolate rows only containing the location reference.

**My desired output would be:**

**Column A:**

```
1. It's nice in France during Summer
2. When I go on holiday
3. When it rains in Spain, the rain etc
4. Icecream is great
5. England is always cold in winter
```

**Column B:**

```
1. France
2. 
3. Spain
4.
5. England
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in BigQuery?

Comment: I have 12 week's worth of data, spread across 15 different Google Sheets - Sheets keep crashing whenever I add complex formulae as each sheet has around 16,000 rows

Comment: If you have a lot of data I would consider moving the whole project to BigQuery. Another question is: how do you identify countries, do you have a list of candidate strings?

Comment: Yep I have a list of candidate strings and my project has already been moved and created as a single table (all weeks) in Big Query.

Comment: So is this about how to write a query to extract the names or how to write the results to a spreadsheet?

Comment: Ok I see - apologies for not being clearer. the query is to extract the names. Then, if possible to write the results to an existing column in the table - if that makes sense?

Comment: Those are two separate and problems though, what have you attempted so far?

Comment: see apps script tutorials. question does not show any attempts regarding the sheets part.

Comment: did you have chance ever to try http://stackoverflow.com/a/39918231/5221944 ? if this answers the `search` part of your question - just focus on second part of it  - which is `how to write to Google Sheets`

Comment: I'm downvoting this question as it doesn't **show** any research effort. For details about what it's expected see [ask].

Comment: @Rubén the OPs previous questions show research effort

Comment: @Pentium10 This question doesn't.

Comment: This is kinda simple for me, just pushing a button and writing out a copy of the sheet that has the additional column. I think the user is not after a fancy real apps script solution, he is just looking for a simpler way.

Comment: BQ already offers you to setup a table as federated input from Google Sheet, technically that is easy, just two clicks from the interface when you start to create the tables. And the query has been provided for the user, after it runs, he just pushes another button, write to Google sheet. That's it.

Comment: @Pentium10: Looking for a simpler way is fine, but even those questions should show the research done, I think.

Comment: Maybe [ask] is obsolete. Do you know something about that?

Comment: well I agree with those articles out there that tell that on SO is damn hard for beginners to ask "accepted". If we could just ignore them until they are above 100 and actually focus on helping them it would make them to learn something on the go, otherwise they will simply ran away from SO.

Comment: Hi guys - thank you so much for all the input! I must apologise for the lack of response, but I've only just finished a hectic day at the office. Firstly, I intentionally didn't include all my research as I wanted to be concise in my question. I understand my initial question may have been too broad but I wanted to get across the 'bigger picture' of what I'm working on. Anyway, I'm going to have a play with the regexp function below and report back with my findings. I really do appreciate the community here at SO - I've been working with Big Query and SQL for a week so am just v curious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done quickly with a SQL that has a regexp compiling all the countries:

```
select line,
ifnull(REGEXP_EXTRACT(line,r'(Andorra|United Arab Emirates|Afghanistan|Antigua and Barbuda|Anguilla|Albania|Armenia|Angola|Antarctica|Argentina|American Samoa|Austria|Australia|Aruba|Aland Islands|Azerbaijan|Bosnia and Herzegovina|Barbados|Bangladesh|Belgium|Burkina Faso|Bulgaria|Bahrain|Burundi|Benin|Saint Barthelemy|Bermuda|Brunei|Bolivia|"Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba "|Brazil|Bahamas|Bhutan|Bouvet Island|Botswana|Belarus|Belize|Canada|Cocos Islands|Democratic Republic of the Congo|Central African Republic|Republic of the Congo|Switzerland|Ivory Coast|Cook Islands|Chile|Cameroon|China|Colombia|Costa Rica|Cuba|Cape Verde|Curacao|Christmas Island|Cyprus|Czech Republic|Germany|Djibouti|Denmark|Dominica|Dominican Republic|Algeria|Ecuador|Estonia|Egypt|Western Sahara|Eritrea|Spain|Ethiopia|Finland|Fiji|Falkland Islands|Micronesia|Faroe Islands|France|Gabon|United Kingdom|Grenada|Georgia|French Guiana|Guernsey|Ghana|Greenland|Gambia|Guinea|Guadeloupe|Equatorial Guinea|Greece|South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands|Guatemala|Guam|Guinea-Bissau|Guyana|Hong Kong|Heard Island and McDonald Islands|Honduras|Croatia|Haiti|Hungary|Indonesia|Ireland|Israel|Isle of Man|India|British Indian Ocean Territory|Iraq|Iran|Iceland|Italy|Jersey|Jamaica|Jordan|Japan|Kenya|Kyrgyzstan|Cambodia|Kiribati|Comoros|Saint Kitts and Nevis|North Korea|South Korea|Kosovo|Kuwait|Cayman Islands|Kazakhstan|Laos|Lebanon|Saint Lucia|Liechtenstein|Sri Lanka|Liberia|Lesotho|Lithuania|Luxembourg|Latvia|Libya|Morocco|Moldova|Montenegro|Saint Martin|Madagascar|Macedonia|Mali|Myanmar|Mongolia|Macao|Northern Mariana Islands|Martinique|Mauritania|Montserrat|Malta|Mauritius|Maldives|Malawi|Mexico|Malaysia|Mozambique|Namibia|New Caledonia|Niger|Nigeria|Nicaragua|Netherlands|Norway|Nepal|Nauru|Niue|New Zealand|Oman|Panama|Peru|French Polynesia|Papua New Guinea|Philippines|Pakistan|Poland|Saint Pierre and Miquelon|Pitcairn|Puerto Rico|Palestinian Territory|Portugal|Palau|Paraguay|Qatar|Reunion|Romania|Serbia|Russia|Rwanda|Saudi Arabia|Solomon Islands|Seychelles|Sudan|South Sudan|Sweden|Saint Helena|Slovenia|Svalbard and Jan Mayen|Slovakia|Sierra Leone|Senegal|Somalia|Suriname|Sao Tome and Principe|El Salvador|Sint Maarten|Syria|Swaziland|Turks and Caicos Islands|Chad|French Southern Territories|Togo|Thailand|Tajikistan|Tokelau|East Timor|Turkmenistan|Tunisia|Tonga|Turkey|Trinidad and Tobago|Tuvalu|Taiwan|Tanzania|Ukraine|Uganda|United States Minor Outlying Islands|United States|Uruguay|Uzbekistan|Saint Vincent and the Grenadines|Venezuela|British Virgin Islands|U.S. Virgin Islands|Vietnam|Vanuatu|Wallis and Futuna|Samoa|Yemen|Mayotte|South Africa|Zambia|Zimbabwe|Serbia and Montenegro|Netherlands Antilles)'),'') as country
from 
(select "1. It's nice in France during Summer" as line),
(select "2. When I go on holiday" as line),
(select "3. When it rains in Spain, the rain etc" as line),
(select "4. Icecream is great" as line),
(select "5. England is always cold in winter" as line) as input
```

this returns:

```
+-----+-----------------------------------------+---------+---+
| Row |                  line                   | country |   |
+-----+-----------------------------------------+---------+---+
|   1 | 1. It's nice in France during Summer    | France  |   |
|   2 | 2. When I go on holiday                 |         |   |
|   3 | 3. When it rains in Spain, the rain etc | Spain   |   |
|   4 | 4. Icecream is great                    |         |   |
|   5 | 5. England is always cold in winter     |         |   |
+-----+-----------------------------------------+---------+---+
```

as you see `England` is not in the list, so you need to adapt to your list. Also I used static data but you can replace that with select from your table.

From here, you have on Web UI option to export the results to a Google Sheet, so you will get the two columns you need. In case the result is too large, you can export as CSV to GCS and upload the CSV into Google Sheet.

I compiled the countries list using this query:

```
SELECT group_concat(country,"|") FROM [gdelt-bq:extra.countryinfo]
```

This is a public dataset, and you can add to your own project https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/gdelt-bq:extra.countryinfo

Comment: this does not answer the (broad) question regsrding google sheets.

Comment: what's exactly the question with that?

Comment: question says "I already know how to search for rows containing a keyword, but I'm not sure how to get Big Query to write to already existing cells in my Google sheet "... i voted too broad.

Comment: That's so simple that people forget it, it's just pushing a button. Maybe the OP just wants this, and nothing advanced with real update in a cell.

Comment: no, see the question. he needs to update specific cells in existing sheet based on results from the query, You've just answered (very well :) only the first part.

Comment: Guys this works fantastic! I modified it slightly to look down all rows of a column - but it does the job brilliantly. Thanks so much :)